# Square root notation and lengths of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals, vectors

I'm reading a textbook and it's going over finding the dot product of two vectors:

$$u * v = \|u\|*\|v\|*\cos\theta$$

The vectors are:

$$u = (0, 0, 1) \\
v = (0, 2, 2)$$

With lengths:

$$\|u\| = 1 \\
\|v\| = \sqrt{8}$$

However, in the text it jumps a little and I'm not sure how they went from $\sqrt{8}$ to $2\sqrt{2}$. What does this mean? $2*\sqrt{2}$ does indeed equal $\sqrt{8}$, but how did it go from one to the other?

Secondly, in the text it then states $cos(45^*) = 1/\sqrt{2}$. I'm not sure how they got to this point either. Where did the righthand portion of that come from? How did they calculate the angle? I lack the foundations of trig/geometry so maybe I should know this, but I just don't.

This is as it appears in the text, without any additional information:

[image]

Comment: $45^\circ$ is one of the [standard angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle_angles_color.svg) for which one is expected to know the sine and cosine.

Comment: If you accept that $2\sqrt 2=\sqrt 8$ that is enough to go between them.  You can use whichever is convenient at the time.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{8} = \sqrt{4*2} = \sqrt{4}*\sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{2}$. You can factor inside the radical and pull out any perfect squares.

Comment: @riista good lucks my friend,thanks for accepting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

angle between  two   vector it is equal

$\cos(\theta)=(u*v)/|u|*|v|$

you know lengths and you know that $u*v=0*0+0*2+1*2=2$

now please insert values

you will have

$\cos(\theta)=2/(1*\sqrt{8})=2/(2*\sqrt{2})=1/\sqrt{2}$

now  use this table

[image]